# Manually calling failureHandler from another controller in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

inb4: I'm VERY new to Spring in general, so I know dealing with SpringSecurity is a steep ride.

**tl;dr:** Can I "throw an exception" from my custom SuccessHandler to my FailureHandler?

Currently I'm trying to achieve some behavior with our login page. In case the credentials are wrong, the user will be redirected back to Login with a message error saying so. In case the credentials used are correct, but another person is already using that account, user will be redirected to Login with a message error saying so ('max sessions error').

So far, using an ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler with Springs built in session/concurrency control works fine, displaying the right error message, but the session control is not working as I expected. This may be either bad config on my own or simply that I don't really understood the documentation (English is not my mother language, so I'm totally open to that possibility). The behavior I want from the SessionControl is that, if a session with a given User is active, the person trying to get in will be kicked back to Login. Currently it does that, but if the User with session actives logs out and tries to log back in, it will kick him/her to login with the MaxSessionsError. AFAIU it's expected because SessionManagement.MaximumSessions() limits the number of log-ins an account have, not the number of active sessions the user can have at the same time. I may be wrong, but I'm still looking into that. I've tried to set up my configuration [as the documentation says](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#session-mgmt), but it's not working as I expect.

My current alternative is to try and throw an Exception on the SuccessHandler when I confirm that another person is currently using an account, so that the FailureHandler can redirect the user to the Login page with the right error message. My understanding is that if I redirect to the Login page, the session won't be destroyed. I can try to destroy it myself, but I honestly trust Spring more to do this due my lack of experience in general, hence my question.

Any help or slap is welcome. I want to learn and I've been a bit negligent with security so far. Below is the code of the config and successHandler. Little note: This project isn't using a web.xml for some reason I don't really know, so I've tried to translate most configs to `@Bean` notation

config

```
/*Other beans and configs*/

@Bean
    ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler exceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler(){
        ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler ex = new ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler();
        String RUTAERROR1 = "/login.zul?login_error=1";
        String RUTAERROR2 = "/login.zul?login_error=2";
        Map<String, String> errores = new HashMap<>();
        errores.put(org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException.class.getCanonicalName(), RUTAERROR1);
        errores.put(SessionAuthenticationException.class.getCanonicalName(), RUTAERROR2);
        ex.setExceptionMappings(errores);
        return ex;
    }

@Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/zkau/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/services/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/images/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/forgotpassword.zul").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/login.zul**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
        .successHandler(customSuccessHandler())
        .loginPage("/login.zul")
        .permitAll()
//      .defaultSuccessUrl("/index.zul")
//      .defaultSuccessUrl("/menuAgrupadores.zul").
        .failureHandler(exceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler())
//      .failureUrl("/login.zul?login_error=1")
        .and()
        .logout()
//      .logoutSuccessUrl("/login.zul")
        .logoutUrl("/j_spring_security_logout")
        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler())
        .and().csrf().disable();
        
        http.headers()
        .frameOptions().sameOrigin()
        .httpStrictTransportSecurity().disable();
        
        http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true);
    }
```

SuccessHandler

```
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Resource
    private UsuariosRepository usuariosRepository;
    private RedirectStrategy redirect = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();
    
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication auth)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        Usuarios user = usuariosRepository.findByUsuario(auth.getName());
        if(user.getToken() != null) {
            throw new SessionLimitException("Max sessions limit reached!", new ProviderNotFoundException("Máximo de sesiones excedido.")); //This is what I'm trying to do
        } else {
            user.setToken(request.getSession().getId());
            usuariosRepository.save(user);
            redirect.sendRedirect(request, response, "/menuAgrupadores.zul");
        }
        
    }
```

SessionLimitException just extends AuthenticationException with no further logic going on.

**EDIT**

As @Eleftheria Stein-Kousathana said, I had missing the listener, BUT I had to add it to a web.xml. As far as documentation goes, this is somewhat obvious, but my application didn't have this file to begin with and every other bean/config was running properly. In other words, the @Bean notation for the HttpSessionEventPublisher wasn't working in my instance. If you are here having the same issue, I strongly suggest you trying both @Bean and XML ways do register this listener. In case you don't know, web.xml should be place in the WEB-INF.

Working code:

```
@Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/zkau/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/services/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/images/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/forgotpassword.zul").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login.zul**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
            .loginPage("/login.zul")
            .permitAll()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/menuAgrupadores.zul")
            .failureHandler(exceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler())
        .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/j_spring_security_logout")
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login.zul")
        .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable();
        
        http.headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .sameOrigin()
            .httpStrictTransportSecurity()
            .disable();
        
        http.sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
            .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry()); //Added this for good measure
```

xml notation of HttpSessionEventPublisher

```xml
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest sticking with the first approach.

The only thing you are missing is an `HttpSessionEventPublisher`.

```java
@Bean
public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
}
```

Once you add this, it will solve the issue with logout and a new user will be permitted to log in.

Without this, the `HttpSessionDestroyedEvent` is not published to the application context on logout and the expired session is not cleaned up.
That is why a new user was not permitted to log in.

Notice in the [`HttpSecurity.sessionManagement` Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#sessionManagement--) it states:

> When using SessionManagementConfigurer.maximumSessions(int), do not forget to configure HttpSessionEventPublisher for the application to ensure that expired sessions are cleaned up.

Comment: Hi, I noticed I didn't have that bean in my code either, so I might deleted it by accident at some point. Unfortunately, even with it the sessionManager kicks further logins to an account, so I can't access twice with the same credentials, even after proper logouts or manually invalidating the session. This is clearly not my intention. What reasons could lead to this even after declarign the EventPublisher? Thank you!

Comment: Hey, an update. It is as you said, but I manage to get it working only adding the listener with a web.xml I created for the sole purpose of testing. Apparently, the @Bean notation is not working (At least in my instance). I have 0 idea as of why, though. Anyway, since it was as you said I'll accept your answer and update my question to make notice of this. And perhaps ask in Github about this. I might have something weird going on with my versions. Thank you!